# Count maximum times record appears in Database table

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to find the proper mysql function but am trying to find the maximum number of a times a single record appears within a database relative to all other records.

For example:

```
  ID   |  ....
================
   1   |  ....
   2   |  ....
   2   |  ....
   2   |  ....
   3   |  ....
   3   |  ....
```

the ideal return for what query i am trying to achieve is 3 (the count of 1 is 1, count of 2 is 3, count of 3 is 2 so return maximum count of ANY id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't nest directly, otherwise you'll get a grouped max.  Nest the selects instead.

```
select max(c) from (
  select
    count(*) c
  group by
    .. whatever ...
  ) x
```

Comment: `Count(*)` grouped by `id` will return a number of rows equal to the number of ID numbers.  The max will then give you the biggest.  Which is what you want, yes?

Comment: forget what i said, im an idiot and had the wrong field name in my actual query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(MAX_COUNT) FROM (SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS MAX_COUNT FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME)
```