# MySQL Count not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, count, mysqli

I'm having trouble using the `COUNT` function in MySQL.
Now, I searched for an answer, and the first thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453342/count-maximum-times-record-appears-in-database-table), however it wanted to count each distinct value.  I found [this About.com](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/counting_records.htm) page which helped me.  Just making sure this isn't a duplicate, but keep reading.

I'm using MySQLi.

My code is simple, I'm trying to count the amount of times in the database, "users," that "admin" is listed as "true."  Keep in mind that it's not `true` as in a boolean, but a string that can contain other values.

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE admin='true'");
```

That didn't seem to work.  I tried adding `echo` in front of the query, but I can't get the amount of times `admin` is true — it should echo `1`.

Am I doing something wrong?  I haven't found much on this subject online and I was reluctant to post it here but... I am :P
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the results:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE admin='true'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
printf ("%s \n", $row["COUNT(*)"]);
```

More info on `mysqli_fetch_array` can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch the results

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE admin='true'");
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
```

according to this page

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

this is untested right now