# Counting the number of times something appears in a column and recording it

Tags: mysql

So in order to know how many people in a table are called Johnny I would need to excecute the following query.

Query:

```
Select count(*) from mytable where first  = 'Johnny';
```

It would give me 2 as the result.

What I wish to do however is record this number in the count column so that the end result comes out like this.

```
+--------+----------+
| First  | COUNT    |
+--------+----------+
| Johnny |        2 |
| Diane  |        1 |
| Johnny |        2 |
| Harold |        1 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Roy    |        2 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Roy    |        2 |
+--------+----------+
```

Is there any query or procedure capable of resulting in this type of output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count maximum times record appears in Database table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453342/count-maximum-times-record-appears-in-database-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your exact output, you need to [use a subquery](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/306bde/1):

```
select
    mytable.First,
    counts.`COUNT`
from
    mytable
join (
    select
        First,
        count(*) `COUNT`
    from
        mytable
    group by
        First
) counts on mytable.First = counts.First;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.First, T2.COUNT
FROM mytable T1 JOIN
     (SELECT First, COUNT(*) as COUNT
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY First) as T2 ON T1.First=T2.First
```

The result will be:

```
+--------+----------+ 
| First  | COUNT    |
+--------+----------+
| Johnny |        2 |
| Diane  |        1 |
| Johnny |        2 |
| Harold |        1 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Roy    |        2 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Amy    |        3 |
| Roy    |        2 |
+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Not quite (note that the Name column is repeated). I think the only way to get this exact output is with a subquery.